# Selecting elements at random

Tags: probability

**Question:** We select an element of $[100]$ at random.  Let $A$ be the event that this integer is divisible by $3$ and let $B$ be that event that this integer is divisble by $7$.  So are $A$ and $B$ independent?

I think they're no, which make sense because $21$ is divisible by both $3$ and $7$.  But I'm confused about how to prove it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $33$ integers in $[100]$ that's divisible by $3$ and $14$ integers that's divisible by $7$.  Therefore as computer nerd has said:

$P(A)=\frac{33}{100}$

$P(B)=\frac{14}{100}$

On the other hand, there're $4$ integers in $[100]$ that's divisible by both $3$ and $7$ (which basically means divisible by $21$), so:

$P(A\bigcap B)=\frac{4}{100}$

Also, just a fact, $P(A)P(B)=\frac{462}{1000}=0.0462$

That should be enough to prove that they're **not independent**.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed they're not independent.

$P(A)=\frac{33}{100}$

$P(B)=\frac{14}{100}$

$P(A\bigcap B)=\frac{4}{100}$

$\therefore$ They're not independent!